Execute requests without waiting for responses
I have a script with the following structure:
Transaction Controller - 1
    Request - 1
    Request - 2
    Request - 3
    
Transaction Controller - 2
    Request - 4
    Request - 5
    Request - 6
    
Transaction Controller - 3
    Request - 7
    Request - 8
    Request - 9
    

Now, Request - 2 takes a good amount of time to respond. So, I would like the other requests to execute without waiting for Request-2.
How do I simulate this?
Note: All the requests are executed sequentially
Please help. Thanks for your support.
Regards,
Ajith

JMeter will wait for the response forever or according to the response timeout which can be set under "Advanced" tab of the HTTP Request sampler

Also JMeter executes requests sequentially and waits for the previous response before kicking off the next request.
If you want to run a "long" request in parallel with "short" requests either move the requests to different Thread Groups or use Parallel Controller
